# Migrating database with hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to migrate data from a Firebird database over to MySQL. I have hibernate setup to create the initial database and now I'm trying to migrate the data over. My initial thought is to setup a second hibernate session connecting to the other database and then looping through to load and save the data but I'm getting no data. I'm wondering if it's even possible to load data from one session and save it into another one.

```
        try (Session mySqlSession = mySqlSessionFactory.openSession(); Session firebirdSession = firebirdSessionFactory.openSession()) {
            mySqlSession.beginTransaction();
            firebirdSession.beginTransaction();

            mySqlSession.createSQLQuery("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0").executeUpdate();
            mySqlSession.getTransaction().commit();

            Criteria criteria = firebirdSession.createCriteria(databaseTable);
            for (Object record : criteria.list()) {
                mySqlSession.save(record);
                mySqlSession.flush();
            }
            mySqlSession.getTransaction().commit();

            mySqlSession.createSQLQuery("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1").executeUpdate();
            mySqlSession.getTransaction().commit();
        }
```